# Removing or disabling the sqlite module

Tags: php, linux

I have compiled PHP 5.3.13 but I don't need sqlite which get installed by default.

How can I remove or disable the sqlite and SQLlite3 module in php?

One option is recompile the whole php stuff which is a hectic job.